# JQuery Hide Div on Click

Tags: jquery, css, hide, show

Basic logic question about `show()` and `hide()`.

When a `li` is clicked, I have a `div` that slides in on top of it. I'm trying to make it so when the `div` that is now visible is clicked, it then hides, but I can't get it to work?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xDg3v/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `e.stopPropagation()` to keep the click event from bubbling up to the `li` and showing the `div`again.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xDg3v/4/